# PDFTK Alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

We've been using a free commandline utility called PDFTK which we make a system call to from a Ruby on Rails app to split PDFs into individual pages. However, it only supports PDF Version 1.4 and back.

Can anyone recommend another utility or gem/Rails plugin to similarly manipulate later version PDFs?

Thanks

Comment: What problems have you had with PDF documents >1.4?  I have used pdftk succesfully on PDF up to 1.7.  It does seem to have some problems with  compressed PDF (Clean up, Object compression options='compress entire file' in acrobat 8 pdf optimizer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk) is built on [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) (dated 2002).  It should be possible to tweak it so that it builds with the latest version of iText, or alternatively install java and call iText directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is another compilation v2.01.
I have tried with v1.5 specs PDF file and it works.

Get it at: http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/