# Linux alternative to pdftk to fill in forms

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-generation

[pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) has had a `libgcj` outdated dependency for years. Unfortunately, that means pdftk can't be installed in any recent RedHat/CentOS/Fedora installation.

I have been searching for alternatives and I can see some people are using tools like `pdfunite` to do some things that pdftk used to do.

Unfortunately, I've not been able to find any tool that extracts form fields data and/or fills a form from the command line. Is there such an alternative?

I can see this was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155422/pdftk-alternative) seven years ago in 2009, but the accepted answer is no longer relevant. The issue in 2016 is the outdated (and unsafe!) dependency. Hence, why I'm creating a new question.

Comment: You can check [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) and [PDF-Shuffler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/).

Comment: I am getting an exception for libgcj.so.14 dependency. :(

Comment: Not really the answer to the question, as it is not an alternative, but still pdftk: you can install pdftk via snap on Fedora (probably on CentOS and RHEL, too — I've only tried it on Fedora though): https://snapcraft.io/pdftk

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF is actively maintained iText clone that includes a Java version of pdftk

Debian is moving to https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk , a Java reimplementation of pdftk which is a drop in replacement (but needs a JRE).